# Custom sagemaker container for training, write forecast to AWS RDS, on a daily basis

Tags: python, amazon-rds, amazon-ecs, amazon-sagemaker, aws-step-functions

I have 3 main process to perform using Amazon SageMaker.

1. Using own training python script, (not using sagemaker container, inbuilt algorithm) [Train.py]

-> For this, I have referred to this link:
[Bring own algorithm to AWS sagemaker](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/train-and-host-scikit-learn-models-in-amazon-sagemaker-by-building-a-scikit-docker-container/)
and it seems that we can bring our own training script to sagemaker managed training setup, and model artifacts can be uploaded to s3 etc.
Note: I am using Light GBM model for training.

2. Writing forecast to AWS RDS DB:

-> There is no need to deploy model and create endpoint, because training will happen everyday, and will create forecast as soon as training completes. (Need to generate forecast in train.py itself)

-> **Challenge is how can I write forecast in AWS RDS DB from train.py script. (Given that script is running in Private VPC)**

3. Scheduling this process as daily job:

--> I have gone through AWS step functions and seems to be the way to trigger daily training and write forecast to RDS.

--> **Challenge is how to use step function for time based trigger and not event based.**

Any suggestions on how to do this? Any best practices to follow? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to trigger Step Functions on schedule is by using CloudWatch Events (sort of cron). Check out this tutorial: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/tutorial-cloudwatch-events-target.html

Don't write to the RDS from your Python code! It is better to write the output to S3 and then "copy" the files from S3 into the RDS. Decoupling these batches will make a more reliable and scalable process. You can trigger the bulk copy into the RDS when the files are written to S3 or to a later time when your DB is not too busy.

Comment: Thanks for answering! Yes, writing to S3 from SageMaker seems to be a best practice, is it? I have couple of questions:
1. Decoupling these batches will make a more reliable and scalable process. Can you please explain this, how it is more scalable?
2. For writing from S3 to RDS, Glue job would be a good option?

Comment: @Parth SageMaker knows how to write the files in batches and can write millions of records to S3. At the same time, inserting millions of records to a database will kill most DBs. For the flow from S3 to the RDS, you can simply use a Lambda function that will trigger the Bulk Update of your DB. Glue can also be used, of course.

Comment: Ok, got it. Thank you very much for detailed answer.

Comment: I have doubt in S3 to RDS forecast writing step. There is glue crawler and glue job set up, which copies newly added file in given s3 folder to RDS database table. Now when writing forecasts, I don't have actual values, so I write NULL. But next day, I have actual of previous day, want that to reflect in S3 and RDS both. Any suggestion, on how to do this? best practice? 

Currently, I am thinking to read and update file in given s3 location, and glue job will pick updated s3 files and perform update on RDS table.
Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Design the schema of your tables in RDS to allow INSERT and not UPDATE. It can make your life easier.